# How do I stop Auto Scrolling of Mathematica 11 when it evaluates a cell?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have a somewhat long code that runs from one cell. I would like the option to look over the code while the cell is being evaluated. However, Mathematica automatically scrolls to the produced output. Is there anyway to disable this?

There doesn't appear to be an option in preferences. Further, I tried to find a work around with `SelectionMove` command. This would only allow me to scroll to a specific cell. For example, `SelectionMove[EvaluationCell[], Before, Cell];` would bring the cursor before the current cell.  Is there a way of going to the current cursor location, for example?